# How can i insert a program in a java utility file?

Tags: java

I want to add this code in my java utility programm,
i wil call this later in another program.

This code will delete files older than 2 days.
i have the following error at line 3
"`Delete cannot be resolved as a type`"

Any help, please, Thank you

```
public void delete(long days, String fileExtension) {
String dirPath = "c:\\Folder";
Delete deleteFiles = new Delete();
deleteFiles.delete(2, ".pdf");
File folder = new File(dirPath);

if (folder.exists()) {

File[] listFiles = folder.listFiles();

long eligibleForDeletion = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);
System.out.println("Starting to clean ...");

for (File listFile : listFiles) {


if (listFile.getName().endsWith(fileExtension)
&& listFile.lastModified() < eligibleForDeletion) {

System.out.println("Deleted = " +listFile);

if (!listFile.delete()) {

System.out.println("Unable to Delete Files..");

    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: How do you check if a file name string `startsWith` some other string?

Comment: What you are looking for is the [FileFilter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_listfiles_file_filter.htm)

Comment: And take your title, put it in a search engine and you'll find your answer. Please do some research before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.startsWith()` inside the loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {

    String s = files[index].toString();

    if (s.startsWith("report"))
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String method:

```
startsWith(String prefix)
```

So in your code you can do this:

```
if(files[index].toString().startsWith("Report")) {
    //print
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Arash Saïdi